# Shortcut with meta-shift key doesn't work in emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, ubuntu

I can't use any shortcut that has meta-shift (alt and shift) in it because ubuntu will treat it as "change keyboard layout" shortcut (I map it to alt-shift since I use the same shortcut in windows) as soon as I press m-s. In windows change keyboard layout shortcut doesn't register until you release the key so any shortcut with m-s is usable in windows.

Is there any work-around without changing shortcut or meta key ?  I kinda used to it.

Comment: Esc or Alt as Meta? Are you saying Both don't work?

Answer (score 3):

Change the Ubuntu `change-keyboard-layout` shortcut, to something else.

Or use <kbd>Esc</kbd> as Meta

Comment: I just don't want to change the shortcut. I'll take it as a final solution. but thanks anyway..

Answer (score 2):

Nothing easy that I know of.

You can manually bind everything that's M-S-??? to C-M-S-??? in your .emacs or at least all of the ones that you use...

Or you can just change the short-cut... how often do you change the keyboard layout? (I use dvorak, and qwerty, but I've never needed a shortcut for it, I just use the button...)

Comment: If there's no easy solution, I think I'll change a "change keyboard layout" shortcut then. It's not that I'm serious about it but I saw how it work in windows, I though there might be an easy solution

Answer (score 0):

I have tried different things, and in my opinion it is best to change the layout shortcut to something else. The power of emacs is all in its shortcuts that are available right there under your fingers. If you move the `M` key away and make it harder to reach, it will most surely have a negative impact on your editing speed.

Right now I'm trying to get used to switching layouts with the right `Alt` key. I almost never use it for anything, so missing it won't be a problem. And from my experience teaching yourself to switch layouts with another combination is a matter of several days.

P.S. Also it pays to use `Caps-Lock` as an additional `Ctrl` key, it helps tremendously!